# Vue JS note transpiling node module

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue app created with `vue create app` and have the following settings in the babel.config file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

My Vue config file also looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    }
  },
  css: {
    extract: false,
  }
}
```

At the moment when I run `vue-cli-service build` it compiles all my modules and styles into 1 bundled JS file.

There is an issue however with one of my NPM modules: `socket.io-client`

It appears that the way that Vue is compiling my app, it is not transpiling something within this package which is causing syntax errors in Internet Explorer 11.

I am fairly sure the problematic code in `socket.io-client` lies with one of it's dependencies called `debug`.

What I would like to do is have this package (`socket.io-client`) also transpiled so that I don't get the error in IE11.

I would have thought that Vue CLI would do this out of the box when you run the build but perhaps something has been setup wrong in my babel or Vue configuration? How could I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transpileDependencies](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies) option in your `vue.config.js`.

> By default babel-loader ignores all files inside node_modules. If you want to explicitly transpile a dependency with Babel, you can list it in this option.

Example:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  transpileDependencies: [
    'socket.io-client'
  ]
}
```

Comment: @redhouse87 I just re-read your question maybe you should try adding a `debug` in transpileDependencies array. And make sure that `npx browserslist` include ie 11.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue here:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1328

Reverting the problematic package to previous version fixed it